# Why each cell of my GridLayout fills the screen

Tags: android, android-gridlayout

I've git a custom view that i want to display as `GridLayout` cell. But each view is streched and fills the entire screen and i don't understand why. Here's the code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/fr.infral.android.test"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:rowCount="2"
    android:columnCount="2" >
    <fr.infral.widget.TileView
        android:id="@+id/tileViewTest_default"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="0" />    
    <fr.infral.widget.TileView
        android:id="@+id/tileViewTest_top"
        android:layout_row="0"
        android:layout_column="1"
        app:primaryAction="@drawable/infral_logo__top"
        app:primaryText="Infral logo&apos;s top" />
    <fr.infral.widget.TileView
        android:id="@+id/tileViewTest_bottom"
        android:layout_row="1"
        android:layout_column="0"
        app:captionAlign="top"
        app:primaryAction="@drawable/infral_logo__bottom"
        app:primaryText="Infral logo&apos;s bottom"
        app:secondaryAction="@drawable/launcher_icon"
        app:secondaryText="What an image !" />
</GridLayout>
```

And here is a summary of what's important in my custom view :

```
public class TileView extends RelativeLayout {

    {
        inflate(getContext(), R.layout.tile_view, this);
    }

    public TileView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public TileView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }
}
```

And the inflated layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/tile_primaryAction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tile_caption"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingTop="16dp"
            android:paddingBottom="16dp"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tile_primaryText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Nocte Caelum" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tile_secondaryText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Lorem ipsum" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/tile_secondaryAction"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:clickable="true" />
    </LinearLayout>
</merge>
```

---

So for clarification : i want to understand why cells fill the entire screen, and how to modify it so that the `GridLayout` fills the entire screen and divides it space among its children.

Comment: don't use the merge tag as parent, use linearLayout and inside it use merge.

Comment: could you please explain why this would help ?

Comment: Just try it to clarify and then ill explain

Comment: Done. I essentially wrapped the last layout code in a `LinearLayout`. The display is better, but editor says : InflateException, merge must be the root element. Besides, using a `LinearLayout` will result in tiles image be upper than caption. A RelativeLayout should be better but the first downfall remains. Did i miss something ?

Comment: Please send me a pic from your app

Comment: What i would like : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44883890/correct.png, and what i obtain : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/44883890/wrong.png

Comment: android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" Matches Parent. So if you put the GridLayout into a linear layout which doesnt fill the entire screen you should be able to solve your problem

Comment: why you don't use the gridView , i think it is better in your case , what do you think ?!

Comment: Understood. What i actually want is the `GridLayout` taking views of any size and make them 'tile' the entire screen, dividing the available space among children. The first link of my last comment shows it. As for GridView, i'd like to enable tiles to span multiple rows or columns which isn't possible with `GridView`.

Comment: Why do you use the `merge` on the inflated layout?

Comment: I don't understand. Could you explain a little ?